# How to save value of a variable after a script is run and increment it by 1 for next run in c#?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to make a script that is going to be used to test our website, part of this includes the incrementation of a variable which needs to then be saved so when the script is run again, that variable will be one greater then the last time the script was run. I know how to increment a variable, its just I have no clue how to save that variable so it wont be reset to its original value at the start of the next run.

For e.g

For first run
count=1

For second run
count=2

Comment: Save it in a separate text file or database.

Comment: Could it be saved within the session? Would using a Cookie be feasible? Or should the value be global for all visitors? Could you write an XML file or even just a simple text file to the file system? How long does the value have to be persisted?

Comment: Using cookie will not be feasible.Value can be global.XML file or text file can be written.Value should be persisted lifelong.